# Logical vector as index in Python?

Tags: python, r, indexing

In `R` we can use a logical vector as an index to another vector or list.
Is there an analogous syntax in `Python`?

```
## In R:
R> LL  = c("A", "B", "C")
R> ind = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
R> LL[ind]
[1] "A" "C"

## In Python
>>> LL = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> ind = [True, False, True]
>>> ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use third-party modules, check out Numpy, specifically [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> LL = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
>>> ind = np.ma.masked_array([True, False, True])
>>> LL[ind]
array(['A', 'C'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

or [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) (helpfully pointed out by @mgilson):

```
>>> # find indices where LL is "A" or "C"
>>> ind = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> LL[ind]
array(['A', 'C'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: I've never used much `R`, but I'm not sure if masked arrays are what OP is looking for or if OP is looking for [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

Comment: @mgilson, what you link to is in fact exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @mgilson: good point! I updated my answer with a boolean indexing example.

Answer (score 5):

In pure Python, though, you might try this

```
[x for x, y in zip(LL, ind) if y]
```

If `ind` and `LL` are Numpy arrays, then you can go `LL[ind]` just like in R.

```
import numpy as np

LL = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
ind = np.array([True, False, True])

LL[ind]    # returns array(['A', 'C'], dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: If you are changing your data analysis platform from R to Python, you want to be using Numpy+Pandas+Matplotlib anyway.